# Find the cell that matches with text "X", then look for the most recent date in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 columns:

Col B: Range of names

Col E: Range of dates

Col G: Dollar values

I want the code to Go in column B, match with whatever name I put cell P5, then see in column E what is the latest date for that name and return the G dollar value. Right now, I have the codes separately but I don't know how to put them together:

```
 Function Max_Date()
   Max_Date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("Y"))
   MsgBox CDate(Max_Date)
 End Function

Function FindText()
 Dim rngX As Range 
  Set rngX = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Find(Range("P5"), lookat:=xlPart)
   If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Found at " & rngX.Address
   End If 
End Function
```

Comment: this can be done with a formula, is vba necessary?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes because it's for other users that may not be familiar with excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could think about something along these line:

```
Public Function GetDollar(NOM) As Double

Dim RNG1 As String, RNG2 As String, RNG3 As String, LR As Double
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    RNG1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(LR, 2)).Address
    RNG2 = .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(LR, 3)).Address
    RNG3 = .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(LR, 4)).Address
    GetDollar = .Evaluate("=INDEX(" & RNG3 & ",MATCH(""" & NOM & """&MAX((" & RNG1 & "=""" & NOM & """)*" & RNG2 & ")," & RNG1 & "&" & RNG2 & ",0))")
End With

End Function
```

[image]

If, in your case, you want to have both column E and G populated, you are going to need two UDF's still as you can't alter other cell's values through UDF.